# How can I use the button of an instance I build dynamically in class

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpushbutton

this script used to build button based on the keys of a dict, and the dict is unknown before call. But I need use the button after the class instanced. So how can I do this ?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys
##build a class
class Ui_Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, graph_obj=None):
        super(Ui_Dialog, self).__init__()
        self.resize(1000, 800)
        self.setObjectName("run dialog")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(20, 20, 20, 20)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        for node in iter(graph_obj.keys()):##this keys is not known in every call
            self.button = QPushButton()
            self.button.setText(str(node))
            self.button.setObjectName(node)
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    targets_graph = {'a': "some contents", 'b': "some other contents"}  ##this dict often changed
    dialog = Ui_Dialog(graph_obj=targets_graph)

    ##I want to build some tasks for the "a button and b button", how can I get the button?
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Possible solutions:
1. connect `clicked` signal of button with a slot right after you create the button 
2. save created button in a container and return that through a method to the requester. 
3. Do `setObjectName("buttonUniqueName")` while creating any button then Use `QObject::findChild("buttonUniqueName")`

Comment: Thank you very much, the method 3 can solve my problem perfectly. I need recall these buttons for arrange and other difficult operations